# How to Write Get Action for layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have layout _PageLayout.
I want to pass some model to layout _PageLayout which can be generate from context that is available in session.
So i want to write Get Action for layout _PageLayout.

Comment: layout pages don't have any httpget or httppost controller action..if you want to display some dynamic data on layout page .. then you can use ajax call..

Comment: Its not clear what you want to achieve. Are you asking how can you pass a model object to a layout page? Why you think you need to define an action method for layout?

Comment: Kartikeya - from where i can give ajax call, from window.load event of layout.   SBirthare - As layout is already used by so many views. So i can't go and add 1 property in every views model that i need for layout.

Comment: yes `window.load` or `$(document).ready()` and make sure you have jquery included in your project.

Comment: @HemantMalpote - Good if you include the caveat in your question itself. Other readers who may not read comments will benefit.

Comment: What about to create a BaseController and catch all the actions
OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)

, maybe if you tell us more about your requirement we can help you a lite more

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass a model to a layout page in the same way that you can pass a model to a view page.

In the layout page you could call a child action method to retrieve the content you require rather than passing a model to the layout.

For example:

In the `_PageLayout.cshtml` page you can include a call to the [child action](http://theshravan.net/blog/child-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc/) like so:

```
@Html.Action("MyChildActionName", "MyActionName")
```

And then you can define a child action in the appropriate controller as follows:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ViewResult MyChildActionName()
{
    var viewModel = //define view model with the contents from your session value here
    return View(viewModel);  //This should return a view that will be rendered within the calling View page
}
```